# JSP Redirect Issue

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, include, forward

I have little problem with redirecting in jsp.

login.jsp

```
<%
Object user = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("User"); 
if(user != null){
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                out.println("<font color=red>You are already logged </font>");
                RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
            }
                %>
```

When user trying access login.jsp page, when he is already logged, this page should redirect him to main page (index.jsp). It works but when I use forward redirecting i don't see message from out.println~ ,also when i use include redirecting i have double main page (but with message :D ). How can i fix it? Whether exists better way to do this wihout using java code in jsp page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `response.sendRedirect("url");`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a user to see a message briefly and then be placed on a different url, it's not called (HTTP) redirect, this is plain old meta refresh:

```
<%@ page session="false" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;URL=http://www.example.com" >
  </head>
  <body>
    A brief message displayed for 2 seconds...
  </body>
</html>
```